# Сделать менее ресурсоемким

Tags: jquery, javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/HappyCougar/B8gU2/10/show/

Сделал вот такой эффект. Но он получился слишком жрущим цпу, чем больше появляется линий, тем меньше между ними расстояния. Можно ли как-то опитимизировать эффект?

P.S Если кто-то видел подобные наработки киньте ссылку.

Comment: рискну предположить, что вам может помочь WebGL

Comment: @HappyCougar, знаете вы толк в извращениях. Почему было не сделать это на canvas?

Comment: @fori1ton я видел и тех, кто на GDI пытался рисовать трехмерную графику)

Comment: Не силен в canvas, но как-то так набросал: http://jsfiddle.net/vSRzy/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать на канвасе - и точка!!!

Answer (score 3):

Тож набросал. Вариант с transitions... http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/d4LVA/1/

Answer (score 0):

Не силён в JavaScript, но рискну подкинуть идею сделать картинку с нарисованными окружностями и растягивать её

Comment: Оригинально однако.